# comments disappear on closure

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

A lot of comments were posted to my question [Subtractive Goldbach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318228/subtractive-goldbach) but they have all disappeared. I don't think that should have happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reviewed the post, and it seems to me that while some comments were deleted by their authors, nothing out of place occurred. One user claimed the question followed from Green-Tao, while another user disagreed. Then both users deleted their comments.